# Grafana visualize cartesian data points (coordinates)

Tags: function, plot, charts, grafana

Is it possible to generate any chart for example line chart that plots on Y axis a function of X where X is not expressed in time but any other unit?

let say you have

f(x) = 2x +1

and would like to plot it for a data range between 1 and 3 so:

x = 1; y = 3;
x = 2; y = 5;
x = 3; y = 7;

If it is possible then how to crate such chart, perfectly working with MySQL DB where in one column you have X, and other column is Y?

I have such example test table (MySQL), X is X axis, Y is value (Y axis) Z is series of data:

```
+---+---+------+
| x | y | z    |
+---+---+------+
| 1 | 3 |    1 |
| 2 | 5 |    1 |
| 3 | 7 |    1 |
+---+---+------+
```

how to write a simplest Grafana MySQL query so it shows data with Plotly?

Comment: Have a look at scatter plot in Plotly panel plugin (https://grafana.com/plugins/natel-plotly-panel).

Comment: @YuriLachin installed that plugin (by extracting content of zip into plugins dir) as I did with many other plugins that work without any problem but this plugin when I click its icon on the list of visualizations to choose from displays an error message: "Panel plugin with id natel-plotly-panel could not be found" do I need some additional steps to install it?

Comment: Did you restart grafana-server after unzip? Also web page reload is required to refresh grafana's javascript modules.

Comment: @YuriLachin yes, did that several times, most of the plugins I installed manually work without any problem but this one doesn't. I have grafana installed on docker and mapped its dir with plugins to host filesystem where i unpacked zip plugins. I worked well for many plugins but this one does not work.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Check if  dirname for plugin matches panel `id` string in `dist/plugin.json` file - they match when plugin is installed via grafana-cli. Don't know dirname after unzip. If it doesn't help try to look for hints in messages in web-developer console of your browser.

Comment: @YuriLachin now it works, but I tired to query data and did display any. Do you know how to write a simplest MySQL query to show an example data above?

Comment: Not for data above, but here is a simple and similar example: `SELECT
  count(name) AS metric,
  latitude,
  longitude
FROM devices
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(myDateTimeColumn)
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY city ASC` should work. And select `Format as: Table` option in grafana's query editor tab.

Answer (score -1):

Stacked bar charts not based on time = huge advantage for Grafana if they can ever figure it out. Until then I will stick it out with Kibana.